# JkMount VS ProxyPassReverse

Tags: apache, tomcat

I've been trying to configure my Java app so that I could send post data to it with jQuery.post(). In my httpd.conf I tried to set it up using ProxyPassReverse like this:

```
ProxyPass        /path/ http://mySite:8080/path/
ProxyPassReverse /path/ http://mySite:8080/path/
```

Doing this works but for only 1 request at a time. So if I send another request before the first one came back I get a 404 status code and no output at all.

Then my Java developer tried to use JkMount:

```
JkMount /path* ajp13
```

But this just sends back the tomcat 404 page.

Navigating to `http://mySite:8080/path/` works fine, so there is no issue with the actual java app.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here or where I can find the logs that might show me something of value?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this last week. To resolve it, I had to mount the path twice.

```
JkMount /path/ ajp13
JkMount /path/* ajp13
```

Comment: The solution we used was something similar. Instead of `/path/` and `/path/*` we used `/path` and `/path/`. It worked in our case. What I'm curious about is why I can link my NodeJS app with ProxyPass but not the Java app.